# Changing the curent page highlight color

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change the highlight menu item when i'm on a current page. But it seems the css is not in my theme's style.css file. It seems like it's somewher in the wordpress css files and can't find it.
http://iulian.cablevision.ro/fc-botosani

So when I click "Stadion" for example I want to change that light red collor to a more intense red just like it dose on hover but can't find out how to do that... I've deleted all the css from the nav menu and it still have the curent page higlight css option

Comment: `wp-content/themes/rookie/rookie.css` **Line 247**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you rookie.css change the bg color on this classes (line 246)

CSS

```
.main-navigation .nav-menu > .current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation .nav-menu > .current-menu-parent > a, .main-navigation .nav-menu > .current-menu-ancestor > a, .main-navigation .nav-menu > .current_page_item > a, .main-navigation .nav-menu > .current_page_parent > a, .main-navigation .nav-menu > .current_page_ancestor > a {
    background-color: #dd3333; // Change color Here
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: woosh! ther it was. thx a lot.... I've tried to inspect the element but a sa newbie in programing I'm kind blind sometimes.

Comment: Additionally worth to be said that alternatively you could overwrite this rule in another css file, instead of changing rookie.css (if you keep your custom files in a separeted one, for manteinance pourposes, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your style.css inside wordpress currectly active theme:

```
.main-navigation .nav-menu > .current-menu-item > a{
    background: #d11919 !important;
}
```